# DBT Jinja Convert Column Name if starts with a number

Tags: jinja2, dbt

This is the macro I use to make sure the column name isnt starting with a number

```
{% macro valid_column_name (column_name) %}
    {% if  column_name[:1]|int(-1) >= 0  %}
        {{ return("_" ~ column_name )  }}
    {% else %}
        {{ return( column_name ) }}
    {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

and then i would call it like

```
select 22 as valid_column_name('1')
```

If anyone wants to improve on this macro feel free

Comment: FYI, the above macro works. There is no need for an "answer" but rather if someone is needing to convert the column name if it starts with a number to an allowed name, then they can use this macro (im sharing it because the page i initially found it on had code that didnt actually work and i had to modify it)

Answer (score 0):

I think your macro is pretty fine. I you prefere to use regular expressions, you can thanks to the [Python "re" module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) [available in dbt](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/modules#re). But your code would not be shorter. `select 22 as valid_column_name('1')` doesn't make a lot of sense because '1' is hardcoded in this example. What is your bigger use case?

With regexp, I would write something like the following:

```
{% macro valid_column_name(column_name) %}
    {% if modules.re.match('^\d', column_name) %}
        {{ return("_" ~ column_name) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ return(column_name) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, i should have clarified what I'm using it for.
Obviously in my actual code its not hardcoded as '1', that was just as an example.

I am parsing out data from 'Podio', which stores everything into one massive JSON file. So in my base layers I'm pivoting it out. However, the issue is that some of the labels they have for the fields arent column friendly, so needed to create a column name that i could alias them as, so that down stream i can reference them